# OS.Rename saving file to wrong folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I am running a script that downloads a file from chrome using selenium and Pyautogui and then renaming it. It is being renamed successfully however the file is being moved to Pycharm Projects.
How do I keep it in downloads or move it to another folder?
Many Thanks
PS. I am a complete beginner so apologies for stupid mistakes.

I have tried shutil.move() following the rename however I do not have the permissions neccasary as the file currently resides in PyCharm Projects.

```
import datetime
import glob
import os
import datetime
currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
xcel_title_ = currentDT.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
current_time = now.strftime("%H.%M.%S")
NF_Name = xcel_title_ + '_' + current_time + '.xlsx'
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\LouisKempson\Downloads\*') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
Excel_Title = ('Sign_In_Summary_' + NF_Name)

os.rename(latest_file,Excel_Title)
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\LouisKempson\Downloads*') # * means 
all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(Excel_Title)
print(latest_file)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the dirctory prefix in `Excel_Title`:

```
Excel_Title = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\LouisKempson\Downloads', 'Sign_In_Summary_' + NF_Name)
```